# Retrieve all values from json array that match a variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a html select element with options(categories). Upon selecting an option(category) I get the option's value and store it in a variable.

```
const currentSelectValue = $('option:selected', this).attr('value');
```

I also have a JSON array with all subcategories.

```
const myObjArr = {
            data: [
                { id: 1, name: 'name_1', parent_id: '1' },
                { id: 2, name: 'name_2', parent_id: '2' },
                { id: 1, name: 'name_2', parent_id: '3' }
            ]
        };
```

My goal is to get the selected option value and match it to the list of subcategories, find the parent_id(which is the value from the selected option) and list all the results.

I'm new to JavaScript, so a detailed answer with an example would be much, much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `currentSelectValue` value is the parent id is it? And if i am not wrong, you want it filter out the matched parent id from `objArr`, am i right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) JS `.filter()`

Assume you have 3 in your `parent_id`. Here is one line clean code solution

```js
const myObjArr = {
  data: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'name_1',
      parent_id: '1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'name_2',
      parent_id: '2'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'name_2',
      parent_id: '3'
    }
  ]
};

// if parent id is 3
const currentSelectValue = 3

const selected = myObjArr.data.filter((ele,index) => ele.parent_id == currentSelectValue
)
console.log(selected)
```